# Is it possible to add a “Formatting” section to the “How to ask a good question” page?

Tags: feature-request, questions, markdown

So I just cleaned up [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1487473/167207): Look at [what was originally posted](https://superuser.com/posts/1487473/revisions) in the revisions history to see what I mean.

I was going to post a comment regarding how proper and basic formatting of the text of a question — including actually making the title a question and not something ridiculous like “For Exchange server Expert” — is important how how a question that is simply badly formatted will be downvoted. And I was going to link to the “[How to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)” page but it oddly — to my mind — does not address formatting.

So why isn’t formatting a part of the content of the “How to ask a good question” page? Cleaned up, the question makes more sense. This applies to other questions and answers as well. So formatting and legibility can make or break content. Why not add that to the “How to ask a good question” page?

Comment: It already has it's own help page. https://superuser.com/editing-help

Comment: We mods don't have the access to change most of the help pages.

Comment: Yeah but maybe you can the right person to change it?